# How can I install Python 2.7 x64 in x64 wine on 12.04?

Tags: 64-bit, wine, python

It keeps failing when I run `wine msiexec /i python-2.7.2.amd64.msi /qn` as recommended as a workaround for an installer bug in some google results.

I just wanted to help the next guy that encounters this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`wine msiexec /i python-2.7.2.amd64.msi /qn` seems not to work.  `msiexec /i python-2.7.2.amd64.msi /qn`, however, does work.